# Comand regex parsing wrong is c# - multiple line

Tags: c#, regex, linux

I am trying to below command in linux OS -
cat /etc/os-release

Response -

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Now i am trying to parse Just version from response with  '(?<=^VERSION_ID=").*(?="$)' expression but it is not matching.

but when i am trying to execute below command
cat /etc/os-release | grep -oP '(?<=^VERSION_ID=").*(?="$)'
Response -  20.04

SO, Why same expression is not working in c# but working in Linux?

sample code for matching --

```
Match match = Regex.Match(response, regex);

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not match");
```

Comment: The regex  you are using to parse the version is correct, but the issue lies with the `Regex.Match` method.

Comment: Because `grep` operates on a line by line basis. In C#, you give the whole string to the regex engine, so male `^` and `$` match line boundaries with `Regex.Multiline` option.

Comment: @Polarcode if issue with Regex.Match , then is there any solutions?

Comment: @DarshitGandhi, yes. You can use `Regex.Maches` and `Regex.Multiline` option.

Comment: `string regex = @"(?<=^VERSION_ID="").*(?="$)"; Match match = Regex.Match(response, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline); Console.WriteLine(match.Success ? match.Value : "No match");`

Comment: @Polarcode I had tried but not got successed ... 
match = Regex.Match(response, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not match");

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I tried multipple line options but not getting success.

Comment: @Polarcode Not error, but just not matching expression

Comment: What happens if you do this instead?

`string regex = @"^VERSION_ID=""([^""]+)""";
Match match = Regex.Match(response, regex);

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not match");`

Comment: Note that in Linux, the `grep -P` option uses Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), which includes lookbehind assertions like `(?<=...)`. This allows you to extract the desired version using the positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=^VERSION_ID=")`, which matches the version that comes after `VERSION_ID="` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: But in C#, `Regex` class uses `.NET` regular expressions, which do not support variable-length lookbehind assertions like `(?<=...)`. It only supports fixed-width lookbehind, meaning the lookbehind expression must have a fixed length.

Comment: The `string regex = @"(?<=^VERSION_ID="").*(?=""\r?$)";` MUST work for you if you pass the whole contents to the regex engine (sorry for a typo, I certainly meant `RegexOptions.Multiline` option).

Answer (score -1):

Your regex should be the following maybe ?

"^VERSION=\"(?<VERSION_ID>[^\"]*)\"$"

Then you catch the version using

```
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["VERSION_ID"].Value);
```